# Understanding my own decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, httpretty

I have written a decorator that is working correctly but i stumbled with the correct solution by trial and error and my litle knowledge about decorators tells me that something is not well defined.

The case is i'm mocking a Rest Api to do some TDD, and this Rest is behind a token security. So before making any request i first must get my user token. I'm using httpretty for mocking the API.

So far i had to register_uri in every test case, one to mock the /token resource and another to test any other resource. But i found that very cumbersome, so a came with a solution to write a simple decorator that would mock the /token and then only had to mock the tested resource.

This is my currently working decorator...

```
def activate_security(func):
    def test_case(test_case):
        httpretty.enable()
        uri = 'http://{}:{}/token'.format(HOST, PORT)
        httpretty.register_uri(httpretty.GET, uri,
                               body=dumps({'token': 'dummy_token'}),
                               content_type='application/json')
        test_case()
        httpretty.disable()
    return test_case
```

And this is how is called.

```
@activate_security
@httpretty.activate
def test_case_one(self):
    #Test case here
```

I had to pass the test_case parameter to the inner function 'cause without it it wouldn't work, and that test_case is test_case_one method, which i thought it would be passed in the func argument, but func in the outer scope holds the object at memory of test_case.

Should't be func the returned value of a decorator? If i do that, the decorator doesn't work. When the inner function is passed that parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are decorating methods, so your resulting wrapper function needs a `self` parameter, just like normal functions being used in a class.

All that is different is that you used a different name fro that `self` parameter, `test_case`. As it happens, the instance is callable, and calling it runs the test, so you are in essence doing `self()` to run the test *again*.

Just name the parameter `self` and pass it to the wrapped function:

```
def activate_security(func):
    def wrapper(self):
        httpretty.enable()
        uri = 'http://{}:{}/token'.format(HOST, PORT)
        httpretty.register_uri(httpretty.GET, uri,
                               body=dumps({'token': 'dummy_token'}),
                               content_type='application/json')
        func(self)
        httpretty.disable()
    return wrapper
```

The `wrapper()` function then replaces the original `test_case_one` function, and when the test is run the `wrapper()` function is bound to the test case instance and will be passed that instance as `self`; in your wrapper you can then call the *unbound* `func()` by simply passing on `self` to it.

For debugging purposes it is often nicer to have some function attributes copied over from the wrapped function to the wrapper; the [`@functools.wraps()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) can take care of these details for you:

```
import functools

def activate_security(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self):
        httpretty.enable()
        uri = 'http://{}:{}/token'.format(HOST, PORT)
        httpretty.register_uri(httpretty.GET, uri,
                               body=dumps({'token': 'dummy_token'}),
                               content_type='application/json')
        func(self)
        httpretty.disable()
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Especially about functools.wraps